# Difference between Model.function(self) and self.function()

Tags: django, function, class, django-models, model

Just a short beginner question. Everything is in the title.

In a django model/python class is there any difference between Model.function(self) and self.function() when calling the function ?

Comment: This isn't specific to Django. No, there's no difference, but you should only do the latter.

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects)